# HTML looping option values in drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, forms, loops, html-select

I have been trying to do a form where a question about one's current age is included, and I have decided the easiest way to answer this question is by filling in a drop down list. So my first value in the drop down list shall be 1900 and then it shall increment by one till it reaches 2014. How do I do that?

Comment: Show what you have tried.Have you tried anything or just posted it for us to answer?Did you do a search?

Comment: Welcome to SO. While asking questions we expect from you to see some code with the focus on a specific issue. Also, provide comments an answers and try to actively participate. See how other people use this site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wouldn't set a fixed final year, why recode again next year?

Note that it is more effecient to update the DOM once than updaing the DOM for each year added to the list.

HTML

```
<select id="year"></select>
```

Script

```
var start = 1900;
var end = new Date().getFullYear();
var options = "";
for(var year = start ; year <=end; year++){
  options += "<option>"+ year +"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/s8HaQ/)

Answer (score 4):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ERasiHoY/1/edit)**

```
<select id="year"></select>
```

```
var year = 1900;
var till = 2014;
var options = "";
for(var y=year; y<=till; y++){
  options += "<option>"+ y +"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
```

Answer (score 1):

a php version?

```php
Birth Year:
<input list="birth_year" name="year_born">
    <datalist id="birth_year">
        <?php 
          $right_now = getdate();
          $this_year = $right_now['year'];
          $start_year = 1900;
          while ($start_year <= $this_year) {
              echo "<option>{$start_year}</option>";
              $start_year++;
          }
         ?>
     </datalist>
</input>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It sounds like the op wanted a javascript / html based solution. There was no mention of PHP. Also an explanation of your code would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="loadAgeSelector()">
<select id="yearselect"></select>
<script>
function loadAgeSelector()
{
var startyear = 1900;
var endyear = 2014;
for (var i = startyear;i<=endyear;i++){
    node=document.createElement("Option");
    textnode=document.createTextNode(i);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("yearselect").appendChild(node);
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```