# how to add default value to dynamic dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html

I found a code on how to make a dynamic dropdown list for selecting years, but I don't know how to add a default value to the dropdown, this is the code i found on

[HTML looping option values in drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873302/html-looping-option-values-in-drop-down-list)

HTML

```
<select id="year"></select>
```

JS

```
var start = 2018;
var end = new Date().getFullYear();
var options = "";
for(var year = start ; year <=end; year++){
  options += "<option>"+ year +"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
```

I tried like this but it doesn't work

```
<select id="year">
<option value=''>Year</option>    
</select>
```

and this

```
var start = 2018;
var end = new Date().getFullYear();
var options = "<option value=''>Year</option>";
for(var year = start ; year <=end; year++){
  options += "<option>"+ year +"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
```

the result I want is like this

```
<select id="year">
<option value=''>Year</option> 
<option value=''>2018</option> 
<option value=''>2017</option>   
</select>
```

anyone know how to do it ?

didn't expext there will be a lot  of answers, thank you guys I'm gonna try your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you were almost there, try below code

```js
var start = 2012;
var end = new Date().getFullYear();
var options = "<option value='' selected>Year</option>";
for(var year = start ; year <=end; year++){
  options += "<option>"+ year +"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
```

```html
<select id="year"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `selected` attribute to one of the `option`s to make it the default selected option.

```html
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option selected>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

```html
<select id="year">

</select>
<script>
var start = 2010;
var end = new Date().getFullYear();
var options = "<option value='' selected>Year</option>";
for(var year = start ; year <=end; year++){
  options += "<option>"+ year +"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var start = 2015;
var end = new Date().getFullYear();

var arrDate = function(start, end) {
    var count = (end - start) + 1;
    return Array.apply(0, Array(count)).map(function (element, index) { 
        return index + start;  
    });
}

arrDate(start, end).forEach(function(v) {
    document.getElementById("year").innerHTML += "<option value='"+v+"'>"+ v +"</option>";
});
```

```html
<select id="year">
<option value=''>Year</option>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to display a default value in your dropdown list of years. Try below code and let me know if that's what you wanted!

html code:

```
<select id="year"></select>
```

js code:

```
var startYear = 2017;
var endYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var options = "<option selected>"+startYear+"</option>";

for(var year = start + 1; year <= end; year++){
  options += "<option>"+ year +"</option>";
}

document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand the question correctly, we want to select the current year.

```
var start = 2017;
var end = new Date().getFullYear();
var options = "<option value=''>Year</option>";

for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
  var selected = year === end ? " selected" : "";
  options += "<option value=\"" + year + "\"" + selected + ">"+ year +"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
```